# Datagridview : Make checkbox column read-only

Tags: c#, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I am using a Datagrid view control to display data. I am using datasource binding to load data.
Datagridview column structure is defined and it has one DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn, which I have made readonly at design time.

 However, this property is not being honoured properly. When data is populated I can still change the value of the checkboxes.

 Can anyone help me to make this column readonly ?

 Disabling this column wipes out my existing values.

Thanks in advance,

Vijay

Comment: It should work, can you post the code, suspect you are doing something else which is removing the property

Comment: Heyy I got it..There was a CellContentClick event handled in my code..Thanks for your reply.